# Filter expected value from list in df column

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame with the following column:

```
raw_col
['a','b','c']
['b']
['a','b']
['c']
```

I want to return a column with single value based on a conditional statement. I wrote the following function:

```
def filter_func(elements):
  if "a" in elements:
    return "a"
  else:
    return "Other"
```

When running the function on the column `df.withColumn("col", filter_func("raw_col"))` I have the following error `col should be Column`

What's wrong here? What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_contains` function:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = df.withColumn("col", f.when(f.array_contains("raw_col", f.lit("a")), f.lit("a")).otherwise(f.lit("Other")))
```

But if you have a complex logic and need necessary use the `filter_func`, it's needed to create an UDF:

```py
@f.udf()
def filter_func(elements):
    if "a" in elements:
        return "a"
    else:
        return "Other"

df = df.withColumn("col", filter_func("raw_col"))
```

Comment: I like the array_contains option. And about the second option, the only thing I was missing is the udf(). My function wasn't an udf so I was not correctly applied to each row of the column right?

Comment: You were applying a native python function to the Dataframe, that's the reason of your error. After adding `udf` annotation, you're telling to Spark to register your function as a Spark function